# how to setup IOServiceAddMatching for different product identifications

Tags: objective-c, macos, libusb, iokit

need to use IOServiceAddMatchingNotification routine for supporing multiple product identifications.
To show the concept, I got part of this code from a site and revised it.Kept it short.

```
// Set up matching dictionary.  
NSMutableDictionary* matchingDictionary;

for (int n = 0; n < numberOfDevices; n++)
{
matchingDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary*)IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName);  

[matchingDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:myVid[n]] forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:kUSBVendorID]];  
[matchingDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:myPid[n]] forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:kUSBProductID]];  

// Set up a notification callback for device addition on first match.  
IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(g_notificationPort, kIOFirstMatchNotification, (CFMutableDictionaryRef)matchingDictionary, deviceAddedCallback, (void*)self, &g_iteratorAdded);  
}
```

I am not sure if it really is correct?. I did not see complains from the xcode and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a nuanced answer - there are three things to note here:

1. In principle, yes, you need to create distinct matching notifications for each independent match dictionary.
2. However, it looks like you're expecting only one `io_iterator_t` to be created and updated with each matching dictionary, as you only have a single variable to store it, `g_iteratorAdded`. **This is not the case. The code shown suffers from a resource leak.** Each successful call to `IOServiceAddMatchingNotification` will create a new iterator, so you will need to retain all of them in an array or so. And then, when you no longer need the notifications (at the latest, when `self` is dealloc'd, or you'll get callbacks on a freed object!), you need to release all of the iterators.
3. For matching multiple different USB product IDs *but identical vendor IDs*, you actually don't need to create multiple match dictionaries and notifications. Instead of `kUSBProductID` with a single `NSNumber`/`CFNumber`, provide a `kUSBProductIdsArrayName` (aka `kUSBHostMatchingPropertyProductIDArray`) and specify an array of numbers. (`NSArray`/`CFArray` containing a `NSNumber`/`CFNumber` for every product ID.)
   Alternatively, if your product IDs match some hex pattern, you can also use `kUSBProductIDMask` in conjunction with `kUSBProductID`: in this case, candidate devices' product IDs will be bitwise masked (`&`) with the number provided for `kUSBProductIDMask` before comparing to the `kUSBProductID`.
   *If you need to match multiple vendor IDs, you will still need to create a matching notification for each vendor ID, and provide the list of product IDs in the `kUSBProductIdsArrayName` value for each.*

##### Update: Sample code for array PID match dictionaries

Some rough untested code for dealing with `kUSBProductIdsArrayName`, assuming your VIDs/PIDs are laid out like this:

```
static const uint16_t myVid[] = { 0x1234, 0x5555 };
static const size_t numberOfVids = sizeof(myVid) / sizeof(myVid[0]);
static const uint16_t myPid[] = {
   // for VID 0x1234
   0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x1001, 0x1002,
   // for VID 0x555
   0x100, 0x101,
};
static const unsigned pidsForVid[] = { 5, 2 };
```

Setting up the matching dictionaries would then look something like this:

```
unsigned next_pid_index = 0;
for (int n = 0; n < numberOfVids; n++)
{
  NSMutableDictionary* matchingDictionary =
    (__bridge_transfer NSMutableDictionary*)IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName);  

  [matchingDictionary setObject:@(myVid[n]) forKey:@kUSBVendorID];  
  NSMutableArray* pid_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:pidsForVid[n]];
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < pidsForVid[n]; ++i)
  {
    [pid_array addObject:@(myPid[next_pid_index])];
    ++next_pid_index;
  }
  [matchingDictionary setObject:pid_array forKey:@kUSBProductIdsArrayName];  

  // Set up a notification callback for device addition on first match.  
  IOReturn result = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(
    g_notificationPort,
    kIOFirstMatchNotification,
    (__bridge_retained CFMutableDictionaryRef)matchingDictionary,
    deviceAddedCallback,
    (__bridge void*)self,
    &g_iteratorAdded[n]);  
  assert(result == kIOReturnSuccess);
}
```

Comment: option#3 is very interesting and promising. How the code in for loop would look like with kUSBHostMatchingPropertyProductIDArray?.

Comment: @fra87kdk I've added a rough example of how I'd adjust your code for `kUSBProductIdsArrayName`; I've not tested it, apologies for any typos!

Comment: this is what have been looking for.  I fixed my code around AddObject and worked for me. thank you.